# mail in bash-script works differently on debian 9 and debian 10

Tags: bash, email, debian

I have a working bash script on debian 9, where i send an email with this mail command:

`echo -e "My mailtext for the mailbody" | mail -s "My subject" -A $PATH_TO_ATTACHMENT -aFrom:From_Name\<A.B@C.de\> to.me@c.de`

That works fine and the content is, as aspected, in the mailbody as just plain text.

The same command works on debian 10 differently. The content isn't in the mailbody anymore but it is attached as ATT00001.txt.

If i use the same command without the `-A $PATH_TO_ATTACHMENT` the content is, as aspected, in the mailbody as just plain text.

Even if i try to set the content type to text/plain the content will be attached as a txt-file.

Is there anybody out there who has a clue why that happens and how i can get rid of it?!

EDIT: The attachment is a txt-file too...

Comment: `mail` can be provided by different packages, the most common being `mailx`. Make sure both systems are using the same `mail` command.

Comment: On both systems is `mailutils` installed and not `mailx`. And the manpage says it is mail.mailutils

Comment: Do the man pages confirm that there is a difference in the use of the `-A` option? Else this may be a Q more suited to the bug report or other supports for the `mailutils` package inside of the GNU(?) organization. Good luck.

Comment: OR is the value of `$PATH_TO_ATT` different on one machine and the other. it is always a good idea to surround variables with dbl-quotes, i.e. `"$PATH_TO_ATT"`. Good luck.

Comment: I tried the command outside of a script without using a variable but have the same problem.
---
There are some changes in the manpage - some options are added. But for the options i use there is no differences. And yes i looked up and tested some of the new options, but it didn't work either.
---
Maybe you are right and i should contemplate to ask somewhere in the GNU organization...

Comment: Good idea to try without any scripting involved. Sorry that didn't solve anything. .... Some systems respond to the cmd `what prog` (`what mail` in your case) by listing all commponents (libraries and .so files) that are included in that program. My impression is that is a Unix only cmd, but if you have it on your linux install, then you will probably see differences between how your `mail` command was assembled. This will be good information to include in any bug report. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

After writing an email to the mailutils bug-report i got an answer. The problem is a bug reported here: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?54992

It was fixed on 15.12.2019 and isn't rolled out yet (13.03.2020). If you want to get rid of it right now the best option is to recompile mailutils from the git HEAD.

They are working on a roll out and looking into getting the bugfix to the debian stable repository soon.

Comment: Wow, bravo for your stick-to-it-ness! and thanks for sharing the results of your research! Good luck to all.